# Bring the "last seen" field back on "profile" page, please

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, profile-page, last-seen

### N. B.:

**This is not a duplicate** of [How could we know “last seen” and “profile views” in profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410618/how-could-we-know-last-seen-and-profile-views-in-profile), as this is a `feature-request` to return the "last seen" like it was presented before, w/o doing some API calls or other circumventing tricks.

---

I observed today, that Stack Overflow introduced a newer design for the "profile" page:

[image]

I have found [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) about new changes, and I agree, that "profile view" count can be a bit less important thing, but

### Could we please have the "last visited" data back?

I really think that "last visited" data is quite important when you need to lookup for how long someone has not been on site. You might need this information for number of reasons:

1. awaiting someone's response/reaction, etc., and check when they were active last time;
2. awaiting acceptance, or comment, or any other responding reaction, and again - being interested in when that person was last online..
3. if I happen to like some old question or answer, want to contribute/comment something and I'm interested whether this person has recently been active, or abandoned the platform for quite some time;
4. etc..

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive

Comment: Looks like it's gone to me. I *wondered* if it was a tooltip for the Visited section, but it is not (and that would not be helpful for others, as only you can see how many times you have visited, and your current consecutive visits).

Comment: @Larnu same here.. checked for a tooltip or popover.. neither is present. Well, that data is quite important and informative, I think..

Comment: I suggest that you counter privacy arguments by suggesting that the indicated time possibly be the most recent of otherwise public info like the time of last non-anonymous publicly-dated public action available from a profile page and/or SEDE (comment, post, edit, close vote, review, etc). (Although such a restriction presumably makes the request non-trivial.)

Comment: "Last seen" was useful to me while I was trying to get the Fanatic badge 

Comment: "3. etc." is not a very persuasive reason. Not sure why that is there if you only thought of two reasons.

Comment: @khelwood because there are some other actions, which I can't enumerate all.. but there certainly are other *related-to-the-matter* actions. One was mentioned by Shridhar, for instance. Besides, `etc.` has exactly that semantical purpose, to be used as an adverb, swapping other *similar* facts/matters/pronouns.

Comment: I added a final reopen vote, but on an off note, it is never a good idea to assume malpractice or bad intent on behalf of the voters. The recent change also led to a bunch of questions so it does seem like a good idea to link together given that the answer is the same: "roll the freaking change back as soon as possible", though.

Comment: @OlegValter I'm not sure I've "assumed any malpractice or bad intent on behalf of the voters", nor I can get the point of this note, as it simply states invalid points. I made a feature request, which is the only stand-alone post, clearly asking for the feature. So, I don't push or force anyone for voting. If you have voted, I'd have better appreciated that without the comments like "I've voted, but you're doing wrong thing". Then why did you vote.. sorry, I just don't agree with your two-sided point. No offense whatsoever, just reasoning about why and what I've possibly done wrong here.(?)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri stating that close voters did not take the time to read your post (or that they do so "blindly") is assuming malpractice on their behalf which I feel is an unjustified accusation, that's my only point. They might've (and likely did) have their own reasons for voting to close. And while I think that the closure was, indeed, incorrect (as did other 4 users), I also do not like villifiying any side.

Comment: @OlegValter this post has been incorrectly related to 1) absolutely irrelevant post for several times, and some users even admitted that they haven't noticed the point of this post (they then retracted closure votes. Check comments), and 2) after I changed the title, as well, to be more explicit, users *still* incorrectly voted for the dupe, while **it is not a dupe*. So, I have the arguments here, in this comment, and I have the same arguments above, in the post payload text. Therefore, point that quite a few people didn't read the post carefully while closing it - has a reasonable basis.

Comment: As useful as it can be, I'm OK with the change. I don't think it's going to change anything particularly critical. If it gets brought back, perhaps it could be made a little more vague though. So instead of a time it could say "in the last day/week/month" for example.

Comment: Some of the uses could be covered by another thing that's even more precise than "last seen": a thing that says "OP has seen this comment/answer" (if that is the case).

Comment: I would love that StackOverflow returns the profile view, and last seen fields

Comment: The discussion you have found contains a [more complete feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368328/147640). It has not been successful.

Comment: IMHO, they're very unlikely to totally roll back the change to "Last seen". They *might* compromise to make it more vague (eg, to the nearest day), but so far I haven't seen any positive response in that direction from the staff. However, [animuson did give some positive feedback regarding my suggestion for a "Last Active" field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1228509_368289)

Comment: @PM2Ring frankly, I think most of us would be all right if they opted to make the field more vague. What is worrying, though, is that they might double-down on the change (happened before with the last big redesign) which is very saddening.

Comment: I miss this feature already.  I often go swimming around in very old pages while searching for dupe targets (ideally canonicals) to close with.  Sometimes I see an old question that needs clarification -- if that asker hasn't been online since 2013, I know that it is a total waste of my time to ask for question improvement (and I am more inclined to instantly vote to close as Needs Clarification).

Comment: @mickmackusa that's exactly one of good usecases. My 3rd point.

Comment: Just another classic example of [so] not engaging with the community and thinking they know what's best. This is a really useful feature and has been around for a long time, why remove it now under the guise of a "responsive layout change"? Where's the discussion with the community?

Comment: Was also very disappointed about this. Another example of someone wasting time trying to look productive changing something that was working just fine to begin with. I wonder if its to do with the new guys Prosus who have bought off stackoverflow :(

Comment: @West (and others), that's a bit harsh. As a UX specialist I'm always looking for ways to simplify and streamline. I'll give the benefit of the doubt here rather than casting aspersions in such a cynical manner. Maybe there was data to suggest that it wasn't useful. Maybe it was done out of sincere privacy concerns. I disagree with removal of the feature, but....

Comment: off note: Aaron and the team have not been brought in with Prosus acquisition, they have been around for a while. It is still a matter of SE being unable (or unwilling) to explain to everyone in each team that every decision that removes something from the community must be discussed first and not imposed top-down.

Comment: @isherwood Not a single good reason has been given so people will naturally suspect any other reasons. The only reason they gave was the field was creepy like seriously thats disrespectful. If there was any such data as you say then they should have shared it. I doubt there's anyone who checks that last seen field for dubious reasons, maybe someones manager but who cares

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, here's a user script you can add to go check the last activity date and insert it into the user's profile.

It should also capture the spirit of the privacy concerns by only presenting other publically available data from when the user has *chosen* to engage on the platform, rather than merely being logged in.

```js
const calendarSvg = `<svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconCalendar" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M14 2h1a2 2 0 012 2v11a2 2 0 01-2 2H3a2 2 0 01-2-2V4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h1V0h2v2h6V0h2v2zM3 6v9h12V6H3zm2 2h2v2H5V8zm0 3h2v2H5v-2zm3 0h2v2H8v-2zm3 0h2v2h-2v-2zm0-3h2v2h-2V8zM8 8h2v2H8V8z"></path></svg>`

const getLastActiveDate = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch('?tab=activity&sort=all')
    const html = await resp.text()
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    const dateDiv = doc.querySelector('.history-table tr:first-child .date_brick')
    const date = dateDiv?.title ?? ''
    return date;
}

const addLastActiveInfo = (date) => {
    const memberSince = document.querySelector('.user-card .list-reset .flex--item:first-child')
    if (!date || !memberSince) { return }

    const lastActive = memberSince.cloneNode()
    lastActive.innerHTML = memberSince.innerHTML
    lastActive.querySelector('.flex--item:nth-child(1)').innerHTML = calendarSvg
    lastActive.querySelector('.flex--item:nth-child(2)').innerText = `Last Active ${date}`
    memberSince.after(lastActive)
}

const main = async () => {
    const date = await getLastActiveDate();
    addLastActiveInfo(date);
}

main()
```

You can add it with a script extension like [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

It's a little brittle because of the CSS classname minification, but should be easy to update if it breaks.

#### Example Screenshot

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: This has broken, there's a working script at StackApps: https://stackapps.com/q/9074/58236

Answer (score -42):

In my humble opinion, removing the field was a good idea. For me it always was a big privacy issue that anyone could see when I'm searching on the page. If this information should be enabled again, please allow us to select if we want to show this information to the public.

---

> **Moderator Note:** This is a perfectly valid answer to the question, no matter how unpopular. You are free to express your disagreement with the answer by downvoting it, but you may not abuse your delete-vote privileges as "super-downvotes". From this point forward, **anyone caught voting to delete this answer is subject to having their account suspended.** There is no imaginable justification for deleting this. (Obviously, feel free to raise a mod flag if you see this deleted.)

Comment: Yeah I can understand that some people aren't comfortable with displaying this info publicly. In this feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368321/598066 I asked for the addition of a checkbox to allow people to choose if they wish to display this information or not. I believe it is a reasonable compromise between forcing this feature on non-consenting people and outright removing it (as it has numerous benefits and is part of a lot of moderation workflow)

Comment: That was definitely creepy. I am glad it was removed. There are many other indicators that show whether the user is still active on the site. It doesn't give you perfect information... Well, it shouldn't.

Comment: @ayhan would you have a suggestion to allow reviewing / editing / maintaining actions on the posts that would satisfy your need for privacy? It really helps when deciding whether to directly edit, or comment at the author, to know if they last came on SO years ago or what.

Comment: In my mind was both useful (nice to get an idea if a user might have seen a comment for example) and a privacy issue. I'm glad it's gone I think, but I'll miss having the information. I think any "checkbox" suggestion would really have to be opt-in, and at that point it's mostly useless.

Comment: An opt-in option wouldn't necessarily be useless imo. Your typical one-time drive-by user most likely wouldn't bother going into options to find the setting, so if I see that a user's last seen is "hidden", I would have at least have some confidence that they know how to use the site, and that in itself is somewhat helpful.

Comment: (...wait opt-in as in opt-in to hide last seen, or opt-in to show last seen? I may have misunderstood :3)

Comment: @ahiijny I meant "opt-in to show last seen". I think if we've decided it's a privacy issue then it shouldn't be on by default because honestly it isn't something you'd think to look for.

Comment: @DavidW ah I see, that makes sense, then. imo I would be fine with opt-out for something like this; it's kinda similar to the "online" visibility indicator on chat messaging apps like Messenger, Discord, Slack, etc. It's on by default, but it should give the user to hide their online presence if they choose.

Comment: I mentioned this already on the meta stackexchange thread, but artfight is a example of a site that has the "show last seen" feature be opt-out (i.e. you can go into settings to hide your last seen). Anecdotally (n=~60) there's about a 5:1 ratio of ppl who have last seen visible vs. have it hidden.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier: I don't think whether a user is active or not should factor into the decision to edit one of their posts but I personally wouldn't mind a "last active" field which refers to my last public action (a post, a comment, a revision...)

Comment: Opt-in is pointless as it will dilute the whole point of the usefulness of the "Last Seen" feature. In my opinion, if people don't like it then don't use [so]. This has been around for years why remove it now under the guise of "responsive layout" changes.

Comment: @ayhan I disagree that it should not factor in, as by experience users can become stressed out when we edit their posts and verifying if they've been here in the last 5 years is a great indicator in whether or not commenting will have any effect. I believe a "last action" field would be great, but I am confused, except from the naming, how does it differ from "last seen"?

Comment: ... oh wait now I see yes. yeah I don't care for the last seen, the last public action is a good compromise. it also makes sense because we could also scrutate a profile to see what their last public action was, so having the field really saves time for the people who want the information, while not exposing anything more than the user has already done, I believe. Good idea @ayhan! Do you know of a post / request somewhere on the network (either here or on meta.se I guess) where it has been requested?

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier: Not that I know of. Some people suggested a less specific version (e.g. last seen today) as a compromise but I think there is response to it yet.

Comment: *...anyone could see when I'm searching on the page.* Is that true? I thought it already worked the way that ayhan is suggesting, which is it just notes the last time you took an action.

Comment: "censored by the masses" is an interesting rewrite of the situation, considering two delete votes necessitates two very high reputation users, which is the exact contrary of "masses" because there are 1. two humans involved (not masses) 2. they are required to have very high reputation (not masses). Like, it's ok to be against the deletion of the answer, but the self-victimization underlying the reaction is childish. Yeah, you have the right to be against the deletion, and these users had the right to use their delete votes.

Comment: @ayhan I cited your comment in a question on mse https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368497/please-show-the-date-of-the-last-public-action-of-an-account-in-the-profile

Comment: @PeterVARGA: You can handle your data/privacy as you wish, and my proposal doesn't forbid it that you share your online status. But please let me decide myself how my data should be handled.

Comment: SO has now also its own Cancel Culture. Very nice!